# Specifying the context root in Jdeveloper 12.2.1 Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, jdeveloper

I'm working on making our company's ADF application to use Maven and have worked out all the issues except one. I cant get JDeveloper to deploy it to use the proper context root instead of ViewController. I have read this sites link which references using the Maven  within the maven-ear-plugin but that wouldn't work since JDeveloper uses its own plugins. Unlike version 12.1.3, JDeveloper 12.2.1 has now locked down and will ignore the JaveEE project properties (Jave EE Web Context Root:) which used to be how this was done.  I have also added the weblogic.xml with the context which shows on the server but has no effect on JDevelper running the application properly.

Has anyone figured out how to override the default setting of ViewController using Maven in this situation and if so how?

Server Log Showing Default being Used:
[04:00:10 PM] The following URL context root(s) were defined and can be used as a starting point to test your application:
[04:00:10 PM] http://999.999.999.999:7101/ViewController
[04:00:10 PM] http://999.999.999.999:7101/Model

Answer (score 0):

The easiest workaround is to rename ViewController project inside your Application.

Answer (score 0):

Even after conversion to a Maven project JDeveloper still seems to use jpr-file for defining the context root. You can change the jpr-file manually:

```
<hash n="oracle.jdeveloper.deploy.dt.DeploymentProfiles">
  <hash n="profileDefinitions">
    <hash n="ViewController">
      ...
      <value n="contextRoot" v="context-root-you-want"/>
      ...
    </hash>
</hash>
...
<hash n="oracle.jdeveloper.model.J2eeSettings">
  <value n="j2eeWebAppName" v="app-name-you-want"/>
  <value n="j2eeWebContextRoot" v="context-root-you-want"/>
</hash>
```

---

The another straightforward way would be to overwrite an JEE application descriptor as `/META-INF/application.xml` **in your EAR-file**. It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="5">
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>ViewController.war</web-uri>
       <context-root>context-root-you-want</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

It should work for every J2EE server and any package tool.

---

Alternately, you can use Weblogic application descriptor `WEB-INF\weblogic.xml` **in your WAR-file** like this:

```
<wls:weblogic-web-app
  xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee https://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app https://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

  <wls:context-root>/context-root-you-want</wls:context-root>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

The method with `application.xml` has higher priority than the method with `weblogic.xml`. See for more information:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#1073750